# Is there a way to efficiently search for a value using 2 keys in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, search

Let's assume I have this table with 3 columns like the one below.
I can make a list of values and simply iterate through every row but that seems inefficient to my rookie eye if there is a lot of data, and it doesn't seem scalable if applied in large projects:

```py
array = [
    ['a', 'x', 100],
    ['a', 'y', 200],
    ['a', 'z', 300],
    ['b', 'x', 150],
    ['b', 'y', 1000],
    ['b', 'z', 50],
    ['c', 'x', 790],
    ['c', 'y', 456],
    ['c', 'z', 500]
]
```

I was thinking of using nested dictionaries, which look more efficient, but are not exactly scalable:

```py
table = {
    'a': {'x': '100', 'y': '200', 'z': '300'},
    'b': {'x': '150', 'y': '1000', 'z': '50'},
    'c': {'x': '790', 'y': '456', 'z': '500'}
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to search for these values? Like indexing on SQL based on two columns.

Comment: Why do you believe a nested dictionary is not scalable?

Comment: Use `pandas` data frame: a table with 3 columns.

Comment: "but are not exactly scalable:" why not?

Comment: @TimurShtatland why? Why not the nested dictionary?

Comment: "Like indexing on SQL based on two columns." What you have is essentially the equivalet of that. Again, it is really unclear *what the issue is*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, If the number of columns becomes high enough, and especially if they are named, a data frame could be a natural structure for this type of data. Of course, for only 3 unnamed columns, other solutions would do as well or even better, avoiding the overhead of `pandas` and the use of extra libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary where the keys are 2-tuples and the values are integers:

```py
{(fst, snd): thrd for fst, snd, thrd in array}
```

This outputs:

```py
{
 ('a', 'x'): 100,
 ('a', 'y'): 200,
 ('a', 'z'): 300,
 ('b', 'x'): 150,
 ('b', 'y'): 1000,
 ('b', 'z'): 50,
 ('c', 'x'): 790,
 ('c', 'y'): 456,
 ('c', 'z'): 500
}
```

which allows for `O(1)` expected time for lookup.

Comment: This isn't Wheel of Fortune, you don't have to pay for vowels. :)

Comment: This! That's exactly what I was looking for! <3

Comment: @BloodyGoldfish this is fine, but why is this *more* scalable than the dictionary you were already using?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm still a bit confused about the terminologies, but I used it for the lack of a better word. I was looking for exactly this ^, or perhaps for a better technology that I just didn't know existed

Comment: @BloodyGoldfish that doesn't make any sense. Again, *why is this better than the `table = ...` you already had?* They are going to both be O(1) lookup, so it isn't clear what *is* scalable about this and what is *not* scalable about the solution you already had

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that I don't have to write every key and value manually if a giant array already exists (or, at the very least it's more appealing to me)

Comment: Oh, *then why didn't you say that*. You can just as easily write code that converts your *list* (not array) to the dictionary you had there. Something like `for first, second, num in array: result.setdefault(first, {})[second] = num` where `result = {}`